# ImportError: cannot import name 'float_factorial'

Tags: python, scipy, python-import, talos

I'm trying to install and import talos (https://github.com/autonomio/talos) to my jupyter notebook. I used "pip install talos" on anaconda3 to install it. Everything went fine, but now when I try to import talos I get the following error:

```
import talos
ImportError: cannot import name 'float_factorial' from 'scipy._lib._util'(C:\Users\myname\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\_util.py)
```

The strange thing is that when I visit this specific folder, there is a float_factorial function so its unclear to me why this is not working. What could be causing this problem and how should I solve it?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I'm using anaconda3, scipy 1.6.1 and talos 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution which works for me. Go to C:\Users\myname\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy_lib_util.py and edit the float_factorial function.
Just rewrite it from this:

```
def float_factorial(n: int) -> float:
    """Compute the factorial and return as a float

    Returns infinity when result is too large for a double
    """
    return float(math.factorial(n)) if n < 171 else np.inf
```

To more simple where I removed the function annotation:

```
def float_factorial(num):
    """Compute the factorial and return as a float

    Returns infinity when result is too large for a double
    """
    val = float(math.factorial(num)) if num < 171 else np.inf
    return val
```

I suppose it is something with Python versions and changes in 3.8